# No Build folder

Tags: reactjs, npm, parceljs

I'm using a parcel bundler instead of a react-scripts which uses `npm run build-prod` instead of `npm run build` but it doesn't create a build folder instead they  all in a dist folder so i changed the deploy script in the package.json to  `"deploy": "gh-pages -d dist"` instead of the standard `"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"` which will give an error saying build script is missing ,  after i tried deploying this to git hub pages but i get an empty screen

```json
 "scripts": {
 "predeploy": "npm run build-prod",
 "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist",
 "clean": "rm dist/bundle.js",
 "start": "parcel src/index.html",
 "build-prod": "parcel build src/index.html"
},
"dependencies": {
 "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
 "react": "^18.2.0",
 "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
 "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
 "@babel/core": "^7.18.5",
 "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
 "@babel/preset-react": "^7.17.12",
 "gh-pages": "^4.0.0",
 "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.5",
 "prettier": "^2.7.1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According the the [Parcel docs here](https://parceljs.org/features/cli/#parameters), you need to specify the `--dist-dir` flag.

Change your `"build-prod"` script to this:

```
"build-prod": "parcel build src/index.html --dist-dir build"
```

Now the output directory for your `parcel build` will go to `build` instead of `dist` so you can change your `"deploy"` script back to this:

```
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
```

Comment: thanks for replying, i got an error saying   "error: unknown option `--dist-dir' "